# Easy tool to convert data to different format

Tags: linux, text-files

I'm studying statistics and programming on my own. What kind of C or Python program will solve the following problem in Linux?

I have a text (maybe CSV) file of the form

```
pcb138  pcb180  pcb52   pcb118  pcb
1,46    ,738    ,532    ,72 19,9959
,64 ,664    ,03 ,236    6,0996
3,29    1,15    ,134    1,54    24,9655
3,94    1,33    ,466    1,94    37,4436
...
32,3    31,5    1,8 8,49    318,7461
```

Now I would like to convert those to another format that another program understands. Namely, a text file of the form

```
pcb138=[1.46,0.64,3.94,...,32.3]
pcb180=[0.738,0.664, 1.15,1.33,...,31.5]
pbc52=[0.532, 0.03, 0.134, 0.466, ...,1.8]
pbc118=[0.72, 0.236, 0.154, 1.94, ...,8.49]
pbc=[19.9959, 6.0996, 24.9655, 37.4436, ...,318.7461]
```

Comment: What are you asking? Yes, a C program can do this transformation. A shorter Python program can do it too.

Comment: Can't find your question and what did you tried so far? Or should this sound like 'here is my work do it for me'!?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot the question mark.

Comment: It looks like you are asking people to write the program for you. This kind of question is not usually well-received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a C program using a 2 dimensional array and strtok() to do the parsing
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```